# open no such file or directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda

I am trying to follow AWS lambda go and s3 examples to create a function which will download the file from s3 resize it and upload back to s3.

When I build the function and run it on local machine, everything works fine, when I run it as lambda I get ""open /tmp/images/users/original/5bba5c0f01e2f_dcadcc7139454bf6dba4cbd01a7c92f8.jpeg: no such file or directory"

Here is my code

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3manager"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
    "github.com/nfnt/resize"
    "image/jpeg"

    "fmt"
    "os"
)


func HandleRequest() (string, error) {
     return runResize("5bba5c0f01e2f_dcadcc7139454bf6dba4cbd01a7c92f8.jpeg"), nil
}

func main() {
        lambda.Start(HandleRequest)
}

func runResize(item_name string) {
    bucket := "bucket"
    folder_name := "images/users/original/"
    folder_name_220x220 := "images/users/220x220/"
    folder_name_250x250 := "images/users/250x250/"
    folder_name_500x500 := "images/users/500x500/"
    folder_name_large := "images/users/large/"

    createFolder(folder_name)
    createFolder(folder_name_220x220)
    createFolder(folder_name_250x250)
    createFolder(folder_name_500x500)
    createFolder(folder_name_large)

    item := folder_name + item_name

    fmt.Printf("Creating file %q \n", item)


    file, err :=  os.Create(item)
    if err != nil {
        exitErrorf("Unable to open file %q", err)
    }

    defer file.Close()

    sess, _ := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String("us-east-1")},
    )

    downloader := s3manager.NewDownloader(sess)

    numBytes, err := downloader.Download(file,
        &s3.GetObjectInput{
            Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
            Key:    aws.String(item),
        })
    if err != nil {
        exitErrorf("Unable to download item %q, %v", item, err)
    }


    if err != nil {
        exitErrorf("Unable to download item %q, %v", item, err)
    }

    // decode jpeg into image.Image
    img, err := jpeg.Decode(file)
    if err != nil {
        exitErrorf("Unable to download item %q, %v", item, err)
    }
    file.Close()


    m := resize.Thumbnail(1500, 1500, img, resize.Lanczos3)
    out, err := os.OpenFile(folder_name_large + item_name, os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        exitErrorf("Unable to resize item %q, %v", item, err)
    }
    defer out.Close()
    jpeg.Encode(out, m, nil)


    m = resize.Thumbnail(500, 500, img, resize.Lanczos3)
    out, err = os.OpenFile(folder_name_500x500 + item_name, os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        exitErrorf("Unable to resize item %q, %v", item, err)
    }
    defer out.Close()
    jpeg.Encode(out, m, nil)

    m = resize.Thumbnail(250, 250, img, resize.Lanczos3)
    out, err = os.OpenFile(folder_name_250x250 + item_name, os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        exitErrorf("Unable to resize item %q, %v", item, err)
    }
    defer out.Close()
    jpeg.Encode(out, m, nil)

    m = resize.Thumbnail(220, 220, img, resize.Lanczos3)
    out, err =  os.OpenFile(folder_name_220x220 + item_name, os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        exitErrorf("Unable to resize item %q, %v", item, err)
    }
    defer out.Close()
    jpeg.Encode(out, m, nil)

    uploadFile(folder_name_220x220 + item_name, bucket)
    uploadFile(folder_name_250x250 + item_name, bucket)
    uploadFile(folder_name_500x500 + item_name, bucket)
    uploadFile(folder_name_large + item_name, bucket)


    fmt.Println("Processed", file.Name(), numBytes, "bytes")
}

func createFolder(folder_name string) {
    if _, err := os.Stat(folder_name); os.IsNotExist(err) {
        os.MkdirAll(folder_name, os.ModePerm)
        fmt.Printf("Folder created %q \n", folder_name)
    }
}

func uploadFile(filename string, bucket string){
    file, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        exitErrorf("Unable to open file %q, %v", err)
    }

    defer file.Close()
    sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String("us-east-1")},
    )

    uploader := s3manager.NewUploader(sess)
    _, err = uploader.Upload(&s3manager.UploadInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
        Key: aws.String(filename),
        Body: file,
        ACL:  aws.String("public-read"),
    })
    if err != nil {
        // Print the error and exit.
        exitErrorf("Unable to upload %q to %q, %v", filename, bucket, err)
    }

fmt.Printf("Successfully uploaded %q to %q\n", filename, bucket)
}


func exitErrorf(msg string, args ...interface{}) {
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, msg+"\n", args...)
    os.Exit(1)
}
```

Here is how I build

```
GOOS=linux go build -v -ldflags '-d -s -w' -a -tags netgo -installsuffix netgo -o resize && zip deployment.zip resize
```

When I run locally, it all works fine, but when running on lambda get, I get the error

Comment: Please ensure that your program listing shown above is *exactly* what you are running and give *exactly* all logged output

Comment: It is the same, I had two version, one with tmp folder and one without, I have removed the tmp so it will be less confusing. The issue is code runs fine on aws instance but does not run as lambda

Comment: I notice you're not checking the error returned from `os.MkdirAll` in `createFolder`. - this may be failing and therefore not creating the download location. Additionally the error message you've supplied doesn't match any you're printing in your code- you format all your errors differently, so where is that coming from?

Answer (score 0):

ok so this code runs first

```
folder_name := "images/users/original/"
folder_name_220x220 := "images/users/220x220/"
folder_name_250x250 := "images/users/250x250/"
folder_name_500x500 := "images/users/500x500/"
folder_name_large   := "images/users/large/"

createFolder(folder_name)
```

making a folder in wherever the program is at the moment

Then it does this

```
 item := "/tmp"/folder_name + item_name

    fmt.Printf("Creating file %q \n", item)


    file, err :=  os.OpenFile(item, os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        exitErrorf("Unable to open file %q", err)
    }
```

when you run it locally it will make the folder in whatever directory you are in

presumably at some point you have made those folders in /tmp too

In the lambda the same thing happens but the lambda function must be running somewhere else that isn't in the /tmp directory

So part of the path isn't found and the program fails

To fix it make

```
folder_name := "images/users/original/"
```

become

```
folder_name := "/tmp/images/users/original/"
```

and remove the "/tmp" + line

Comment: The code runs fine if I run on local server on aws not as lambda

Comment: I try both local path and tmp, both cases it fails on lambda runs fine on aws server